# How to change cursor positions unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to move my cursor to positions but i cant finds how to do it

I tried some ways but they didnt works

is it even possibles or no s
so any ideas on this problems s

i dont want to use custom cursors s
Doess
anyone know how to do it s

Comment: Have you tried to use Mouse.current.WarpCursorPosition method?